# Divergent sums of reciprocals of specific natural numbers

Tags: analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is known that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \sim \ln(n)$$

and

$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}}^n \frac1p \sim \ln(\ln(n)),$$

with the property that the difference in each case converges to a constant (Euler–Mascheroni and Meissel–Mertens constant, respectively).

Let's write $A_1 = \mathbb N$ and $A_2 = \mathbb P$ (the set of prime numbers). Can this principle be continued in the sense that there is an interesting description of a subset $A_3 \subset \mathbb N$ (or maybe even $A_3 \subset A_2$) such that

$$\sum_{k \in A_3}^n \frac1k \sim \ln(\ln(\ln(n)))$$

or, in general, $A_i \subset \mathbb N$ (or maybe even $A_i \subset A_{i-1}$) such that

$$\sum_{k \in A_i}^n \frac1k \sim \ln^{i}(n), \quad \text{where }\ln^i = \underbrace{\ln \circ \dots \circ \ln}_{i\text{ times}},$$

each with the property that the respective difference converges to a constant?

Comment: I guess you mean the sum to be on $k\in A_i, k\le n$. There is always the trivial solution: take for the next $k$ the smallest possible such that the sum stays below $\ln^i n$. The real question is: are there interesting sets $A_i$ besides $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb P$?

Comment: Yes, I should have written $k\le n$ below $k\in A_i$ to avoid confusion.
Exactly, that's my question. Are there interesting sets like prime numbers with a specific property for $A_3$? What could be such a property?

Comment: What you denote $\ln^i$ is often denoted $\ln^{\circ i}$. (Having said that, I think number theorists often use $\ln^i$ for it anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I remember a number theory book that I can't find now stating that the sum of the inverses of numbers of the form $n \log n$ diverges as $\log \log n$.  The primes are very much like those because of the prime number theorem.  It went on to say that the sum of the inverses of the numbers of the form $n \log n \log \log n$ diverges as $\log \log \log n$ and the pattern continues.  It said that if you raise the last term to the $1+\epsilon$ power in any of these the sum converges.  This is a quite natural progression.

No proof was given, but converting the sum to an integral makes it make sense.  $$\int \frac {dx}{x \log x \log \log x}= \log \log \log x +c$$ for example.

Comment: Thanks! However, one $\log$ after the equal sign is missing.

Comment: @Thrash:  You are right.  Fixed.  Thanks